# Am getting error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while implementing Serializable

Tags: java

Am writing a program on sending Serializable data over a UDP network it throws up an error on the server. it the error comes about when i call this particular line on the server obinnas ok = (obinnas)In.readObject();. Below is my program.

Server Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(7000);

            socket.setSoTimeout(0);

            while (true) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                ByteArrayInputStream buffers = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
                ObjectInputStream In = new ObjectInputStream(buffers);
                obinnas ok = (obinnas)In.readObject();

                String message = new String(buffer);

                ok.print();
            }

        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Obinnas Class on Server

```
public class obinnas implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID  = -4507489610617393544L;

    String name;
    int data;

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(name +": "+data);
    }

}
```

Client Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        String host = "localhost";
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        obinna Details = new obinna("Jay", 1);

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream In = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

        In.writeObject(Details);
        In.flush();

        byte[] Buf= buffer.toByteArray();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(Buf, Buf.length, addr, 7000);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4000);
        socket.send(packet);


    }
        catch (Exception error){
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The error message I get is below

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.obinna
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:682)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1859)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1745)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2033)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at server.Server.main(Server.java:28)
```

Comment: The class mentioned is not available on the CLASSPATH when deserializing.

Comment: *Obinnas Class on Server* I guess that this is not the same code as on the `client`.  This class does not seem to implement the necessary methods

Comment: @EJP can you pls explain what you meant by the The class mentioned is not available on the CLASSPATH when deserializing

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand. It seems perfectly clear to me. And why are you naming an output stream as `In`?

Comment: @EJP I have you got an idea on how i can setup the CLASSPATH. am using netbeans

Comment: You don't have to 'set up the CLASSPATH'. You just have to deploy the class named in the exception to the server. And see my answer.

Comment: Sorry @EJP that am disturbing you but I still don't get how to do this. Can you give me an example Pls

Comment: Sigh. You have deployed your server main class to the server, and your `obinnas` class as well. You only have to *also* deploy `client.obinna` in exactly the same way. No mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing a `client.obinna` object and trying to deserialize it as an `obinnas` object, in whatever package `obinnas` is defined.

This will not work.

It *is* an `obinna` object, and trying to typecast it to another class will fail even after you solve the underlying problem, which is that the class mentioned in the exception is not available on the CLASSPATH when deserializing.

You can't do this. You have to use the same class, with the same name, in the same package, at both ends.